# Configure Project Quota

Tags: server, fstab, xfs, quota

hello im trying to setup a quotas system for project in my server the problem is the quotas is not working i dont know why this is my fstab file

```
# BEGIN AUTOGENERATED SECTION -- DO NOT REMOVE
192.168.100.204:/backups         /backups             nfs          defaults         0 0
/dev/omics/homes                 /omics/homes         xfs          defaults,_netdev,usrquota  0 0
/dev/omics/projects              /omics/projects      xfs          defaults,_netdev,prjquota  0 0
/dev/omics/tools                 /omics/tools         xfs          defaults,_netdev 0 0
# END AUTOGENERATED SECTION   -- DO NOT REMOVE
```

this command gives me this result xfs_quota -x -c 'free -hb'

```
xfs_quota: project quota flag not set on /omics/projects/ipt-omics
xfs_quota: project quota flag not set on /omics/projects/easigdiab
xfs_quota: project quota flag not set on /omics/projects/Virologie
```

i made 2 files /etc/projects and /etc/projid and added my projects there and when i type this command `xfs_quota -x -c 'report -pbih' /omics/projects/` i get this

```
ipt-omics       0   2.4T   2.9T  00 [------]      0      0      0  00 [------]
easigdiab       0   900G  1000G  00 [------]      0      0      0  00 [------]
```

but i get nothig for the virologie directory and i cant modify the quotas for other one too it seems like the quota is stuck or something

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve the problem, i was adding the folders munually to /etc/projects

and it didnt work so make switched to a command to do that

```
xfs_quota -x -c 'project -s -p /omics/project/Virologie 400' /omics/project
```